# Caption label formatting in Context

Tags: captions, context, context-mkiv

I am trying to introduce a linebreak after the caption label so that the caption starts below the caption label in `context`. However, the `suffix` key for the `\captionsetup` only accepts text like `:` or `--`. I would like something like this:

[image: Caption label above the caption.]

MWE:

```
\setupbodyfont[modern,11pt]
\setuplayout
  [width=11cm,
   rightmargin=6cm]

\setupcaption
  [figure]
  [width=\rightmarginwidth,
   headstyle=smallcaps,
   suffix={:},
   prefix=yes,
   way=bysection,
   prefixsegments=chapter,
   align=right,
   location={rightmargin,high}]

\starttext
\showframe
\chapter{One}
\placefigure{A cow is a cow is a cow.}{\externalfigure[cow]}
\stoptext
```

Comment: You can set `\setupcaption[figure][distance=\textwidth]`.

Comment: @Marco Thanks. I see the option on the contextgarden page for `captionsetup` but didn't see any description. Neither does `contextref.pdf` that comes with texlive2012 has any info. Where did you find this? Also, if you could write this as an answer with the explanation about how this works, that would be great.

Comment: Using `distance=\textwidth` is an ugly hack. The right way to do this is to use `spaceinbetween=none`, or, if you want a different space `spaceinbetween=small|medium|big|<dimen>`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\setupcaption
  [figure]
  [distance=\textwidth]
```

The `distance` key specifies the space between the suffix and the
actual caption text. I actually looked into the source to find out
the possible options. The manual and wiki are both helpful and
mostly provide detailed explanations, but are often incomplete. The
sources are – by definition – complete and up-to-date.

In `strc-flt.mkvi` you find that the default value for `distance`
is `1em`:

```
\setupcaptions
  […
   \c!distance=1em,
   …]
```

Further down this value is assigned to `\scratchskip`. Now you know
that `distance` is a glue value with the default size of `1em` and no
stretch or shrink which is being inserted between the suffix and
the caption text. If this value is increased beyond the size of the
surrounding box (the actual value does not matter) ConTeXt places
the content on the next line.